# Need the X to show on the grid for hit or miss

Tags: c#

This is a C# program for a battleship game. When the user inputs their guess, I need either a black X for miss or a red X for hit to display on the grid. I rendered the original grid and added letters for columns and numbers for rows. I'm not sure what I need to do to get the hit and miss to show up on the grid and could use some suggestions. This is my very first C# program so I'm a little new to this.   Thanks!

```
    //the basic grid
    private static readonly char[,] Grid = new char[,]
 {
    {'.', '.', '.', '.', 'S', 'S', 'S', '.', '.', '.'},
    {'P', 'P', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'},
    {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', 'P'},
    {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', 'P'},
    {'.', '.', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', '.', '.', '.'},
    {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', 'B', '.', '.'},
    {'.', 'S', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', 'B', '.', '.'},
    {'.', 'S', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', 'B', 'P', 'P'},
    {'.', 'S', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', 'B', '.', '.'},
    {'.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'},
 };

    public static void printGrid(Char[,] Grid)
    {

        //Improve the rendering so that the grid 
        Console.WriteLine("     |  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |  E  |  F  |  G  |  H  |  I  |  J   |");
        Console.WriteLine("-----#-----#-----#-----#-----#-----#-----#-----#-----#-----#------#");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (i == 9)
            {
                Console.Write(" {0} ", i + 1);
            }
            else
                Console.Write(" {0}  ", i + 1);
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                ShipColors(Grid[i, j]);
            }

            //match header
            Console.Write("  |\r\n");
            Console.WriteLine("-----#-----#-----#-----#-----#-----#-----#-----#-----#-----#------#");
        }
    }

    //declare colors of each ship
    public static void ShipColors(char color)
    {
        /*
         * A = Aircraft Carrier
         * B = Battleship
         * P = patrol boat
         * S = Submarine
         * H = Hit
         * M = Miss
         
         
        */
        switch (color)
        //color ships
       
        {
            case '.':
                Console.Write(" | ");
                //Blank space here needed to be added for formatting the cells properly.
                Console.Write("   ");
                break;
            case 'A':
                Console.Write(" | ");
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                Console.Write(" A ");
                break;
            case 'B':
                Console.Write(" | ");
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
                Console.Write(" B ");
                break;
            case 'P':
                Console.Write(" | ");
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkBlue;
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
                Console.Write(" P ");
                break;
            case 'S':
                Console.Write(" | ");
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
                Console.Write(" S ");
                break;
            case 'H':
                Console.Write(" | ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.Write(" X ");
                break;
            case 'M':
                Console.Write(" | ");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Console.Write(" X ");
                break;

        }
        Console.ResetColor();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Just a quick comment: `guess.Substring(0, 1);` and `guess.Substring(1, 1);` do nothing in your code (other than to throw an exception if the user input is less than 2 characters.

Comment: You probably want two `Grid` variables. One for where the ships are, the other for the hit / miss the player can see.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it so it works better. So now it will display if there is a hit or a miss but I need the x to show on the grid, which I think i need another loop but I cant seem to get anything to work.

Comment: FYI You can perform maths on character constants `if (userGuess[0] < 'A' || userGuess[0] > 'J') { .... }`, `userGuess[0] - 'A';`

Comment: It's working perfectly now.  You are awesome! thanks again for all your help!

Comment: Why did you delete your other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71633645/c-sharp-placing-ships-on-a-grid-within-the-range-of-the-users-input-of-the-grid

Answer (score 0):

After you have validated the player's move, you're showing what they did;

```cs
if (char.IsLetter(Grid[rowNumber, colNumber]))
{
    Console.WriteLine(userGuess + " is a HIT!");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine(userGuess + " is a MISS.");
}
```

But you aren't storing anything to remember it.

Do you want to show the player where the ships are? Or do you want to reveal them only when they are hit?

I would create a second grid to represent the "fog of war", as visible to the player.

```cs
private static readonly char[,] FOW = new char[,] { ... };
```

Assign the Hit or Miss into that array;

```cs
if (char.IsLetter(Grid[rowNumber, colNumber]))
{
    Console.WriteLine(userGuess + " is a HIT!");
    FOW[rowNumber, colNumber] = 'H';
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine(userGuess + " is a MISS.");
    FOW[rowNumber, colNumber] = 'M';
}
```

And print it instead;

```cs
printGrid(FOW);
```

When the game is over, you can print the grid showing where all the ships really were.

Comment: I want to show the ships for now and replace the letter with a red X if hit and if its a miss add a white X to that spot in the grid. I don't need to hide the ships.

Comment: You still need to write the result into your `Grid` variable.

Comment: ok Its working! Thank you sooooo  much!

Answer (score 0):

I've made a version of your code that does what you want and might give you some coding ideas moving forward.

The key thing I did was to define a second grid for your guesses.

```
    char[,] grid = new char[,]
    {
        { '.', '.', '.', '.', 'S', 'S', 'S', '.', '.', '.' },
        { 'P', 'P', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.' },
        { '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', 'P' },
        { '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', 'P' },
        { '.', '.', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', '.', '.', '.' },
        { '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', 'B', '.', '.' },
        { '.', 'S', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', 'B', '.', '.' },
        { '.', 'S', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', 'B', 'P', 'P' },
        { '.', 'S', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', 'B', '.', '.' },
        { '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.' },
    };

    int numbers = grid.GetLength(0);
    int letters = grid.GetLength(1);

    char?[,] guesses = new char?[numbers, letters];
```

The above code is the first part of the `Main` method.

The grid `guesses` is automatically created with every value being `null`. When you get a hit or a miss you can assign `H` and `M` respectively.

I changed `printGrid` to `PrintGrid` to follow the C# naming conventions.

I also made `PrintGrid` responsible for all `Console` manipulation. It's job is to display the grid, plus any messages.

```
static void PrintGrid(char[,] grid, char?[,] guesses, int numbers, int letters, string message)
{
    Console.Clear();

    var colors = new Dictionary<char, (ConsoleColor back, ConsoleColor fore)>()
    {
        { 'A', (back: ConsoleColor.Black, fore: ConsoleColor.Yellow) },
        { 'B', (back: ConsoleColor.Black, fore: ConsoleColor.Cyan) },
        { 'P', (back: ConsoleColor.Black, fore: ConsoleColor.DarkBlue) },
        { 'S', (back: ConsoleColor.Black, fore: ConsoleColor.Red) },
        { 'H', (back: ConsoleColor.White, fore: ConsoleColor.Red) },
        { 'M', (back: ConsoleColor.Black, fore: ConsoleColor.White) },
    };

    IEnumerable<char> GetRow(int n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < letters; i++)
        {
            yield return guesses[n, i] ?? grid[n, i];
        }
    }

    void WriteLine(int? number, IEnumerable<char> line, char filler, char separator, bool useColors = false)
    {
        Console.Write($"{number}{filler}".PadLeft(5, filler));
        Console.Write(separator);
        foreach (var c in line)
        {
            Console.Write($"{filler}{filler}");
            if (useColors && colors.ContainsKey(c))
            {
                Console.BackgroundColor = colors[c].back;
                Console.ForegroundColor = colors[c].fore;
            }
            Console.Write(c);
            Console.ResetColor();
            Console.Write($"{filler}{filler}{separator}");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    WriteLine(null, Enumerable.Range(0, letters).Select(n => (char)('A' + n)), ' ', '|');
    WriteLine(null, new string('-', letters), '-', '#');
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers; i++)
    {
        WriteLine(i + 1, GetRow(i), ' ', '|', true);
    }
    WriteLine(null, new string('-', letters), '-', '#');

    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message))
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.Write("Enter your guess (e.g. A2) or Q to quit: ");
}
```

It has also been written to handle any practical size grid - just change the initial definition of `grid` to have any number of rows or columns you like.

Finally, to display a hit or a miss rather than the ship in the grid I've included this code:

```
yield return guesses[n, i] ?? grid[n, i];
```

This returns the guess if there's a value and the underlying grid value if there isn't.

The remainder of the code in the `Main` method is this:

```
    char lastLetter = (char)('A' + letters - 1);
    Regex regex = new Regex($"^([A-{lastLetter}])(\\d{{1,2}})$");

    string message = "";

    while (true)
    {
        PrintGrid(grid, guesses, numbers, letters, message);

        string userGuess = (Console.ReadLine() ?? "").ToUpper();

        if (userGuess == "Q") return;

        Match match = regex.Match(userGuess);

        if (match.Success)
        {
            int rowNumber = int.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value) - 1;
            if (rowNumber < numbers)
            {
                int colNumber = userGuess[0] - 65;
                bool isHit = char.IsLetter(grid[rowNumber, colNumber]);
                guesses[rowNumber, colNumber] = isHit ? 'H' : 'M';
                message = $"{userGuess} is a {(isHit ? "HIT" : "MISS")}!";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            message = "Guess must be in the form of ColumnRow, like: B5";
        }
    }
```

Here's an example of a smaller grid in action:

```
     |  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |
-----#-----#-----#-----#-----#
   1 |  .  |  .  |  .  |  .  |
   2 |  P  |  H  |  .  |  .  |
   3 |  .  |  M  |  A  |  A  |
   4 |  M  |  .  |  .  |  .  |
   5 |  .  |  S  |  .  |  .  |
   6 |  .  |  S  |  .  |  .  |
   7 |  .  |  S  |  .  |  .  |
   8 |  .  |  .  |  .  |  .  |
-----#-----#-----#-----#-----#

B2 is a HIT!

Enter your guess (e.g. A2) or Q to quit:
```

I hope this is of interest.

Comment: Wow, thanks for your help! This is really useful, it helps me understand c# a lot better also.  I've learned so much in just a day already just from stack overflow alone.

Comment: My pleasure. It would be lovely to get an upvote.

Comment: I tried, I'm new to stack overflow so this is what I get  when I try to upvote "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."